# Autohotkey - send ctrl+ to auto adjust column width in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, autohotkey, explorer

Using Autohotkey, I'd like to send "ctrl+" to File Explorer, to auto adjust column width.
Manually, it's ctrl+   (the + in the numpad).

This code below works, but only for first level folders, not if I open a folder within a folder.
Is there a way to send "ctrl+" again for each subfolders I might open?

```
Gui, +LastFound
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt, WinExist())
MsgNum := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str, "SHELLHOOK")
OnMessage(MsgNum, "ShellMessage")
Return

ShellMessage(wParam, lParam) {
 wTitle = ahk_id %lParam%
 WinGet, pname, ProcessName, %wTitle%
 If (wParam != 1 || pname != "Explorer.exe")
  Return
 WinActivate, %wTitle%
 Send ^{NumpadAdd}   ;ctrl+ (numpad)
}
```

Comment: `Send ^{NumpadAdd}` (which is the correct way), works just fine for me. Could you show your whole script? The problem is probably somewhere else. Or is this the whole script?

Comment: This is the whole script.It works if I assign the "send" to F9 for example: F9::send ^{NumpadAdd}

Comment: Yes, indeed it would work from a hotkey like that. So what exactly is the problem you're having, or what are you asking for help with?

Comment: Looks like Dolphin975 wants upon opening explorer window, columns to be adjusted automatically without any user intervention?

Comment: Yes, as lww said.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Gui, +LastFound
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt, WinExist())
MsgNum := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str, "SHELLHOOK")
OnMessage(MsgNum, "ShellMessage")
Return

ShellMessage(wParam, lParam) {
 WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %lParam%
 If (class = "CabinetWClass")
    Send ^{NumpadAdd}   ;ctrl+ (numpad)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Relax!  

It's been a surprise to have a solution after almost 3 years!  
It works great.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to convert Relax's script to Autohotkey V2.
I used Quick Convertor V2 but I got "Invalid callback function" here when running th script:

```
005: OnMessage(MsgNum, ShellMessage)
```

I think in V2 the syntax should be (that's what I actually wrote)

```
OnMessage MsgNum, ShellMessage
```

but when the error appears it shows "OnMessage(MsgNum, ShellMessage)"

Here's my V2 code:

```
myGui := Gui()
myGui.Opt("+LastFound")
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", "UInt", WinExist())
MsgNum := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "Str", "SHELLHOOK")
OnMessage MsgNum, ShellMessage
Return

ShellMessage(wParam, lParam) {
class := WinGetClass("ahk_id " lParam)
If (class = "CabinetWClass")
Send("^{NumpadAdd}")   ;ctrl+ (numpad)
}
```

Comment: `MsgNumber  
Type: Integer  
  
The number of the message to monitor or query, which should be between 0 and 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF).  
If you do not wish to monitor a system message (that is, one below 0x0400), it is best to choose a number greater than 4096 (0x1000) to the extent you have a choice.  
This reduces the chance of interfering with messages used internally by current and future versions of AutoHotkey.`  
  
Source:[link](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/OnMessage.htm)